Fail to build in Vercel but works perfectly fine on local
I am trying to deploy my project on Vercel. It works fine on local but whenever I deploy it through Vercel, it gave me an error "npm run build" exited with code 2. Below is the error
senior-project-fe/book_components/ModalAddNewBook.tsx(2,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap/Button' or its corresponding type declarations.
senior-project-fe/book_components/ModalAddNewBook.tsx(3,19): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap/Modal' or its corresponding type declarations.
senior-project-fe/book_components/ModalAddNewBook.tsx(4,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-toastify' or its corresponding type declarations.
senior-project-fe/book_components/ModalAddNewBook.tsx(5,19): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'axios' or its corresponding type declarations.

And this is the import for ModalAddNewBook.tsx
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
import toast from 'react-toastify';
import axios from 'axios';

I have set git config core.ignorecase false but it doesn't work.
This is my tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2020",
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  }


Have you run npm install as a pre-build step?
